# Yahoo oauth2 - getting access token from code

Tags: yahoo-api

I am trying to integrate my application with Yahoo oauth2 login. I am not using any external libraries and following the instructions in https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/

I generated authorization URL, redirected user to the login page of yahoo and got the code (completed steps 1-3 in the Yahoo guide).

Now I have to pass this code and get the access token. (Step 4: Exchange authorization code for Access Token)

For that, I am using the code as given below

```
$fields_string = 'grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri='.$CALLBACK_URL.'&code='.$code;
$fieldCount=3;

$ch = curl_init();

$headers = array(Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode($CONSUMER_KEY.':'.$CONSUMER_SECRET),
    'Content-Type:x-www-form-urlencoded'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, $fieldCount);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

curl_exec($ch);
result = curl_exec($ch);
```

But this is not working and I am not getting any response from Yahoo. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved it. Call was made similar to get_access_token method inside https://github.com/saurabhsahni/php-yahoo-oauth2/blob/master/YahooOAuth2.class.php